# One alert when importing a production database

Tags: database, mysql, database-error

I now have a local copy of a live EE site. Front and backend are working with no problems.

However, when I imported the production database I got this one alert:

[ERROR in query 912] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Should I be worried?

These are the first lines in the sql file:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.5
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Oct 29, 2013 at 07:18 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.29-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 5.3.17

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
```

Any idea?

Comment: Not certain but I think you'd have to find the 912th query in the dump... and look at the first line of *that query* not the first line of the dump...

Comment: Mmmh... My knowledge of SQL is not good. How do I actually locate that "query 912", once I imported the database?

Comment: Again, not certain, but as queries are delimited by semi-colons perhaps you could search for the 912th semi-colon.

Comment: For testing purposes, if you export the database from your localhost and then re-import that export does it product the same error? If not, I wouldn't worry about it. Plus, I suggest always exporting you db with "DROP tables syntax" added and gzipped.

Comment: I followed @stephen-callender advice. I exported the database from my localhost and then re-import it. I didn't get any errors this time. And learning to always exporting my db with "DROP tables syntax" added and gzipped. Thanks Stephen! Having said that... is it resolved? I probably have a data issue remaining there.

Comment: Try it again with the drop tables and gzipped. Same error?

Comment: Sorry, but that is madness. If you import the data and there is an error on import, then there will be something that has either not imported, or it's imported incorrectly, either way, that problem is not exactly gone it's just that the data that was the issue is not in the db anymore.

So if you export it locally and reimport it locally, of course the problem will have gone, because the problem isn't there locally now.

You still need to get the data in from the live site without error or you may have lost data or have it in the system wrong.

Comment: You're right. My earlier comment was madness. Wasn't thinking.

Comment: @SergioAcosta, open your sql in a text editor and then copy/paste into here http://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/ OR here http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm - Any errors/warnings?

Comment: OK, I made a new dump from production (with Drop tables syntax and zipped), then imported it locally using Sequel Pro and I got NO errors or alerts anymore.  Reason to celebrate?

Comment: @SergioAcosta, celebrate away. Glad I could help even in my madness. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes these errors happen because of the connection or application used in exporting the db. I'd recommend using Sequel Pro to export the db with DROP tables syntax and gzipped. If you still see the alert/error, then there's really something wrong.